# How to append elements to an empty list within an empty list?

Tags: python, list

I would like to append to a single list within a list, without appending to all the 'sibling' lists at the same time.

Suppose I have an empty list of empty lists in Python, such as the following:

```
    from math import pi
    test = [[]] * 3
    test
    Out[88]: [[], [], []]
```

Now suppose I want to append an element only to the first nested list. I would say that selecting the first list, index 0:

```
    test[0]
    Out[89]: []
```

and appending to that list as follows:

```
    test[0].append(pi)
```

should yield a list that looks as follows:

```
    [[3.141592653589793], [], []]
```

However, when printing the result, I get the following:

```
    test
    Out[91]: [[3.141592653589793], [3.141592653589793], [3.141592653589793]]
```

Can anyone point out where I am making my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious, where did you find/learn that `[[]] * 3` thing?

Comment: I don't quite recall, just a logical consequence of list concatenation, I guess? That is, if `[1] + [1] + [1] = [1, 1, 1`], it seems only logical that `[1] * 3 = [1, 1, 1]`, too.

Comment: Try: `test = [[] for i in range(3)]` newline `test[0].append(pi)` newline `print(test)`

Comment: The issue is that when you do `[[]] * 3` the nested lists are all the same object in memory.

Comment: I see. People keep making this mistake, and I was wondering who/what was responsible for teaching it to them.

Comment: Ah I see. That seems like an easy thing to overlook.