# Appending to an empty list - Python

Tags: python

```
posts = []

#response = feedparser.parse(url)

# existing titles is equivalent to [x['title'] for x in posts]
existing_titles = []
for x in posts:
   existing_titles.append(x['title'])
```

What is this code suppose to do?
[How to append elements to an empty list within an empty list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517502/how-to-append-elements-to-an-empty-list-within-an-empty-list)
I have seen this stackoverflow above that puts the append in every value of list, but im not still quite understanding what this code does because of x['title'], since posts is empty

Comment: For loop will not perform because posts are empty

Comment: Question that you linked is different than what you have asked. There might be some code in between `posts = []` and `existing_titles = []` which is updating `posts`.

Comment: What does it do currently? From the looks of it it does nothing. What it looks like it should be doing is taking the dictionary entry named title from each entry in the posts list

Comment: posts[] shoudnt be there then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posts is a map of list with same key i believe, something like .

```
[{'title':'Test'},{'title':'this is test'},{'title':'en'},{'title':'tech'}]
```

Comment: posts[] shoudnt be there, right?. its stupid, right?

Comment: Yes, @JimmyHiluzzi it seems, but we cannot say for sure unless we have context

Comment: Believe me, it is, I changed the code. Sorry for the wasted time.